# Why are enums in java public and static implicitly by nature?

Tags: java, enums, static, public

I have been recently studying java enums and couldn't understand why they are implicitly public and static by nature. final I understand because they are constants but why the other tags?

Comment: They are `static` so that the constants are associated with the class instead of an instance of the class. This ensures the constants are singletons, and that you can reference them without first needing an instance of the enum (which would not be possible to obtain as you are not allowed to instantiate enums yourself). They are `public` so that they are visible to outside code. Not sure what else to say about that, other than you control the visibility of an enum by changing the visibility of the enum class itself.

Comment: As a counter-question: why would you think it makes sense for them not to be `static` or `public`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have been recently studying Java `enums` and couldn't understand why they are implicitly public and static by nature.
>
> `final` I understand because they are constants but why the other tags?

It is complicated, but I think you have some of the facts incorrect there.

According to the Java 17 Language Specification ([JLS 8.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9))

- *"It is a compile-time error if an `enum` declaration has the modifier `abstract`, `final`, `sealed`, or `non-sealed`."*

  See below.
- *"A **NESTED** `enum` class is implicitly `static`. That is, every member `enum` class and local `enum` class is `static`."*

  And non-nested classes are implicitly static too.
- *"It is a compile-time error if ... an enum declaration has **MORE THAN ONE OF** the access modifiers `public`, `protected`, and `private` (§6.6)."*

  But that is the same as any other class.  This doesn't say that it is implicitly `public`.
- *"An `enum` class is either implicitly `final` **OR** implicitly `sealed` ..."*

  There is something rather subtle going on here.  If an `enum` constant has a class body, then it actually defines an anonymous subclass of the `enum` class.  In this case, the `enum` class is not final in the sense of "having no subclasses"

---

So:

1. Enum classes are NOT implicitly `public`.  They can be `private`, for example.
2. Enum classes MAY BE implicitly `final` in the "has no subclasses" sense.   But you were using `final` in the "constantness" sense.  The binding between an `enum` constant name and the corresponding value cannot change; i.e. it is implicitly final in that sense.

   However, the `enum` values can have mutable fields, so they are not *necessarily* constant in the sense that `42` is a constant.  Just like you can change the array content with the following "constant":

   ```
    final int[] CONST = new int[]{1, 2, 3};
   ```
3. Enum classes ARE implicitly `static` in contexts where another class *could* be non-static.

Why are they implicitly static?  Well if they weren't, what would it mean?  An implicitly static `enum` is effectively a set of singleton values.  But it it wasn't, then each time you created an instance of the class that enclosed the `enum` class, you would be creating a *new set* of `enum` values.  They are no longer singleton.  This would be most unexpected ... and I am finding it hard to see how it would be useful.

Answer (score 3):

If you would look at Java documentation, it is clearly mentioned that:

> Programmers can not invoke constructors of enum.

which basically means that we can not create any object of enum using the keyword `new`. Now if enums weren't static, then how would we access them without any instance/object?

```
enum Color { RED, GREEN, BLUE; } // enum declaration
Color.RED //accessing enum constant
```

If you have noticed only have to access enum constants is through enum name (similar to how we access static members of any class).
So to be able to access enum constants without any object we need them to be static.

And enums are by default public so that we can freely access them anywhere however this is not a necessity we can use private or protected modifiers as well.

Comment: Note that an enum doesn't  have to be public, it can be private.